# DateRangePicker cancelBtn duplicate items redirect to the same page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a pos system with three areas using the DateRangePicker plugin.
Everything works perfectly except for the cancel button.

For the first 2 areas, I used different classes

```
$(".daterangepicker.opensleft .range_inputs .cancelBtn").on("click", function(){

    localStorage.removeItem("capturarRango");
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location = "ventas";
})
```

and

```
$(".daterangepicker.opensright .range_inputs .cancelBtn").on("click", function(){

    localStorage.removeItem("capturarRango2");
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location = "reportes";
})
```

I have one open to the left and other to the right, so when I click on the cancel button each page refresh on its own.

The problem is to the third, I don't know what else can I change or add so it won't overwrite any of the other two.

```
$(".daterangepicker.opensleft .range_inputs .cancelBtn").on("click", function(){

    localStorage.removeItem("capturarRango3");
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location = "caja-diaria";
})
```

Like this, both items that have the .opensleft class will be redirected to the same page.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Regards!